# Курсор vs цикл. Есть ли преимущества?

Tags: sql

Встречал время от времени в коде принебрежение курсорами-когда вместо того, что бы открыть курсор делалась итерация по какому-то первичному ключу с инкрементом. Я в курсе, что курсоров лучше по возможно избегать, но разве от явного цикла есть какой то профит?

Пример:

```
    Declare @idx INT=[какое-то стартовое значение, возможно инициализация какого значения из какой-то таблицы]
    While @idx<=[какая-то константа, возможно какое-то значение из таблицы]
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Table]
        SET [Field]='bla bla bla'
        WHERE [какое-то поле]=@idx
        --или что-то такое
        Declare @TMP Nvarchar(255)
SELECT @TMP=field from [table] WHERE [какое-то поле]=@idx
--Дальше какая-то хитрая логика с @TMP

        SET idx =idx +1
    END
```

Comment: по мне так циклы еще большее зло. если конечно внутри цикла в зависимости от неких условий не происходит резких переходов на много значений вперед, без выборки промежуточных записей.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, а  где сказано, что курсоры нужно избегать?

Comment: @0xdb, да так все поголовно говорят.

Comment: Хмм, я например такого не говорю, или мы говорим о разных вещах. А пример для сравнения вы можете дать?

Comment: @0xdb, так уже добавил пример обхода курсора

Comment: @0xdb когда база огромная курсоры очень медленно работают

Comment: короч, есть на мой взгляд не плохая статья на это https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: [Oracle cursors vs for loops ...](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1838616387113)

Comment: Стоит ли обсуждать этот вопрос в рамках стандартного SQL? Пока в предложеных ссылках говорится о разных вещах, которые (могу ошибится) разные производители понимают по своему.

Comment: В стандартном SQL, вроде, нету курсоров. Но я его добавил, что бы асбтрагироваться от СУБД.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вообще то есть [тык](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)).